# How to read data through multiple classes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter project at work and I've hit a plateau..

I've got a models folder in which I've created a class that basically holds a List of objects with a specific property that I would like to change inside a widget. I would then like to see the change of this property be reflected on the List afterwards for then to be able to read the property in another widget/screen. I can easily change the property INSIDE the widget, but due to the scope, the change is NOT reflected on the List from the models folder.

I have a screen in which I render several Card widgets. These card widgets are rendered and build from the before mentioned List of objects. Every Card has a constructor that takes in three properties, ONE of these properties is the particular property I would like to be able to read when it's being changed inside the Card widget state. However, I don't know how to do that.

List<Object(property 1, property 2, property 3)> -> build Card(property 1, property 2, property 3) -> changing property 3 inside Card.
How do I change the actual property inside the List?

1. This is the List I'm referring to.

```dart
class AvailablePlans {
  static List<PlanCard> planChoices = [
    PlanCard(
      plan: 'American Football',
      isMarked: false,
      variants: [''],
    ),
    PlanCard(
      plan: 'Soccer',
      isMarked: false,
      variants: [
        'Soccer 11v11',
        'Soccer US 9v9',
        'Soccer US 7v7',
        'Soccer US 4v4',
        'Soccer DBU 8v8',
        'Soccer DBU 5v5',
        'Soccer DBU 3v3',
        'Soccer SvFF 3v3',
        'Soccer SvFF 5v5',
        'Soccer SvFF 7v7',
        'Soccer SvFF 9v9',
      ],
    ),
    PlanCard(
      plan: 'Baseball',
      isMarked: false,
      variants: [],
    ),
    PlanCard(
      plan: 'Standard Geometry',
      isMarked: false,
      variants: [],
    ),
    PlanCard(
      plan: 'Extended Geometry',
      isMarked: false,
      variants: [],
    ),
    PlanCard(
      plan: 'Free Form Text',
      isMarked: false,
      variants: [],
    ),
  ];
```

2. This is from inside the screen/widget in which each Card is being build with the properties from the List. The property I would like to read is the 'isMarked' property!

```dart
SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return PlanCard(
                  plan: plans[index].plan,
                  isMarked: plans[index].isMarked,
                  variants: plans[index].variants,
                );
              },
              childCount: plans.length,
            ),
          ),
```

3. Inside the Card widget where I change the isMarked LOCAL variable in the setState. However, Id like to also change the ACTUAL isMarked property for the desired object inside the List.

```dart
class PlanCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String plan;
  final List<String> variants;
  bool isMarked;
  bool isExpanded = false;

  PlanCard({this.plan, this.isMarked, this.variants});

  @override
  _PlanCardState createState() => _PlanCardState();
}

class _PlanCardState extends State<PlanCard> {
  void _saveStateFromBoxes() {
    setState(() {
      widget.isMarked = !widget.isMarked;
      print(widget.isMarked);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the individual property of a list you need you to get access every element and then call the property.

```
class PlanCardView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<PlanCard> planCards;

  PlanCardView({
    Key key,
    this.planCards,
  }) : super(key: key);
   
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: planCards.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        PlanCard planCard = planCards[index]; //getData;
        return Container(
          child:Text(planCard.isMarked)  //access isMarked
      );
    }
  );
}
```

You need to pass the PlanCard list to this class and then it will print all the isMarked property at the Text Widget